При верной отправке пароля и логина выдает что пользователь не найден
При верной отправке пароля и логина выдает что пользователь не найден.
Я новичок в PHP,помогите разобраться,по возможности не только советами
<?php
$login = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'login');
$pass = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pass');

$pass = md5($pass."ghjsfkld2345");

$mysql = new mysqli('localhost','root','','registracia-bd'); 
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login' AND `pass` = '$pass'";
var_dump($login, $pass, $query); 
$result = $mysql->query($query);
if($result > 0) 
{
 $user = $result->fetch_assoc(); // Конвертируем в массив
 setcookie('user', $user['name'], time() + 3600, "/");
 $mysqli->close();
 header('Location: /');
}
else
{
    echo "Такой пользователь не найден";
}

?>

Посмотрите, чему равно значение $result перед if. Поидее, там должно быть не число, а открытый курсор с набором найденных строк

Так и есть, запрос выполняется и выводит данные,которые я ввожу при входе. Все верно, а дальше мне необходимо задать условие, при котором будет происходить проверка на наличие такого пользователя в БД

скорее всего result false

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701142/191482 - до кучи к другому дубликату

Я в совершеннейшем изумлении. Где, ГДЕ в 2024 году можно встретить учебник, который предлагает писать вот это всё? Мухосранский сельскохозяйственный техникум, преподаватель - дедушка, который Куликовскую битву видел?

@АлексейШиманский скорее всего result true. А в остальном всё верно, надо отображение ошибок включать. Ну и плюс нормальный учебник.

Я понимаю,что нас не особо обучали, на просторах интернета куча материала, вот и понемногу ото всюду приходится собирать. Я же написала  не для того,чтобы меня палками закидали

@Ипатьев  Я правильно понимаю, мне необходимо перед всем кодом добавить проверку на все ошибки и посмотреть результат?

Вам надо найти нормальный учебник. А не тот, где показывают всё это - md5($pass."ghjsfkld2345");, WHERE login = '$login'. И там где написано, как проверять результат запроса. В идеале - Джон Дакетт. Но сойдет и Котеров
